# "unrecognized selector" when trying to listen for UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotificationcenter

I have a "static"-like class that I want to be able to respond to low memory warnings. However when I trigger the low memory warning manually from the simulator I'm receiving an "unrecognized selector" error.

Relevant code:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
+ (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification*) notification;
@end 

@implementation MyClass
+ (void) initialize {
    [super initialize];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification) name:@"UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification" object:nil];
}
+ (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification*) notification {
    // Breakpoint here never hits.
    // I instead receive error "+[MyClass receiveNotification]: unrecognized selector sent to class".
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method name is `receiveNotification:` (note the colon is part of the name)

So the selector should be `@selector(receiveNotification:)`

EDIT: also, btw, I wouldn't call [super initialize] in a class initializer. Similarly, you should guard against a subclass causing this initializer you wrote to be invoked twice. See this very nice post from Mike Ash for more on this: [class loading and initialization](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-05-22-objective-c-class-loading-and-initialization.html)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Ah. That did it. Strange-- why wouldn't there be a compile-time error to catch that mistake?

Comment: Because the compiler cannot know that @selector(receiveNotification) is not the one you want. A selector isn't tied to a particular class, so as far as it knows, some other class might implement it. Or your class might implement it in some other compilation unit, or even add that method at runtime. The compiler also can't know that the observer passed to `-addObserver:selector:name:object:` is supposed to implement the selector argument -- Objective-C doesn't provide any way to tell the compiler about that relationship.